# What is the difference between ClassName objectName(4); and ClassName objectName = 4;

Tags: c++

```
    class Pizza() {
        private:
            int value;
        public:
            Pizza(int x) {
                value = x;
            }
    }

    int main() {

        // What is the difference here under the hood?
        Pizza p1 = 2;
        Pizza p2(2);
    }
```

The reason I ask this is that if I have a Pizza constructor that takes a string,

```
    Pizza p3 = "letters here";
    Pizza p4("letters here");
```

The line with p3 produces a type conversion error. This is because the actual type it is looking to take is const char*.

The line with p4 works fine. Why is it that when "letters here" is in ( ), it is made a string object, but when "letters here" just comes after the = sign, it's type is const char*.

Comment: One is an assignment (`operator = (...)`) and the other a constructor. You should use the constructor in C++, it's likely more efficient. Although with all optimizations, it often becomes the same code in assembly.

Comment: @AlexisWilke incorrect. Both are constructors.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Both call the same constructor!

Comment: Please post a MCVE with the code that doesn't work

Comment: The constructor in your example code takes an integer, not a string. Please don't simplify the issue away. If the question requires a constructor that takes a string, then your example code should include a constructor that takes a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a constructor that looks like this.

```
Pizza(std::string x) {
  ...
}
```

And you're calling it like this.

```
Pizza p3 = "letters here";
Pizza p4("letters here");
Pizza p5 = Pizza("letters here");
```

`p4` and `p5` are fine. We call the `Pizza` constructor with a `const char*` argument. We need an `std::string`, and there's a handy implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`, so it all works. `p3` is different; we're trying to *convert* a `const char*` to a `Pizza`. We have a conversion from `const char*` to `std::string` and one from `std::string` to `Pizza`, but the C++ compiler will only do one implicit conversion per argument, so it won't take those two hops we need to get there.

There are two ways around the problem, if you still like the `p3` syntax.

1. We could write a constructor that *takes* a `const char*`, which would require only one implicit conversion so everything would check out. The constructor could even delegate to the `std::string` version, if we want the same behavior.
2. We could explicitly cast to `std::string`, as `Pizza p3 = std::string("letters here");`. Again, this only requires one implicit conversion, so the compiler would accept it.

Comment: I think you should start with the fact that each are different types of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Answer (score -1):

Confusingly for newcomers, both syntaxes in your string-example are calls to the same constructor!

```
Pizza p3 = "letters here"; //the same as Pizza p3("letters here");  !!!
Pizza p4("letters here");
```

Comment: arr... not quite. They are different types of initializations with different rules. C++ is very very complicated when it comes to initializations.

Comment: @bolov in this case they're the same  (the only difference would be if the constructor were explicit, or we were using old versions of C++)

Comment: @M.M I don't even dare to enter the world of rules for intializations. I take your word for it :)

Comment: @bolov Have a look at the first two lines in this example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor for this specific situation

Comment: If they would be the same they would actually work the same, which they don’t.

Comment: They resolve to the same constructor, the issue here (as Silvio pointed out in his way better constructed answer) is that more than one user-defined implicit conversion would be required to actually call the applicable constructor...